# Running NUnit tests programatically [Could not find reference]

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I'm trying to run WebDriver + NUnit test from .txt file via .NET Framework console app, here is my demo code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string source = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\SomeTest.txt");

        Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"CompilerVersion", "v4.0"}
        };
        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);

        CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters
        {
            GenerateInMemory = false,
            GenerateExecutable = false,
        };

        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("nunit.framework.dll");
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("WebDriver.dll"); 
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("nunit.core.interfaces.dll");
        compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("nunit.core.dll");

        compilerParams.OutputAssembly = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.dll";

        CompilerResults compileResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParams, source);

        var assembly = compileResults.CompiledAssembly;

        CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
        SimpleTestRunner runner = new SimpleTestRunner();
        TestPackage package = new TestPackage(assembly.Location);
        if (runner.Load(package))
        {
            TestResult res = runner.Run(new NullListener(),
                TestFilter.Empty, false, LoggingThreshold.Off);
        }
    }
```

and I'm ending up with this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'nunit.core, Version=2.6.4.14350, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96d09a1eb7f44a77' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Here are my references:

[image]

Does anyone know what is the issue here?

Comment: You might need to make sure that those NUNit DLLs are placed in the same folder as your generated DLL -- I'm not sure exactly what `TestPackage` is doing, but it's unlikely that it's loading that generated DLL into your AppDomain, so all of the generated DLL's dependencies need to be resolvable

Comment: So the issue is the output folder of generated DLL? Where then to generate the DLL?

Comment: If my guess is right -- it doesn't matter where you generate it, what matters is that the NUnit DLLs it references must also be in that directory

Comment: I set up the output folder to be `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` where all of the other dll's are, but I ended up with same error.

Comment: I found the issue, Copy Local property of these references must be set to true. It works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, Copy Local property of these references must be set to true. It works now